# Import huge mysql dump with single insert

Tags: mysql

I need to import huge MySQL dump ~500mb of a single table but the problem is dump file with single insert statement and with multimple rows. When i try to import it to database it takes a so long time that i'm not shure will be it finished or MySQL just gone away. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

several things you can do:

1. get a binary dump from the original and import that.
2. get the original db data files and copy them across.
3. Edit the 500mb file into several, you edit the single sql insert statement to be many sql insert statements. All you need to do is put some closing brackets after, say, 100 rows of values, then put the 'insert into x' statement on the next line. Repeat.

Comment: as the way to solve i wrote my own program which convert db dump, after all thx for involve